# How Mac-then-encrypt provide security in nonce-misuse setting?

Tags: authenticated-encryption, nonce

From [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/202/should-we-mac-then-encrypt-or-encrypt-then-mac), it is clear that Encrypt-then-Mac provides more complete  security than Mac-then-Encrypt but some schemes use Mac-then-encrypt to provide nonce-misuse resistance such as SIV (AES-GCM-SIV, AES-CCM-SIV) or [DEOXY II](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1IUELtBUdp6vrY8uhxHhycsGuSH_XlpMJ/view), [ESTATE](https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Events/lightweight-cryptography-workshop-2019/documents/papers/estate-authenticated-encryption-mode-lwc2019.pdf)  by generating a tag and use it as IV for the encryption part.

**Q.** How is the use of Mac-then-encrypt provide nonce-misuse security?

Comment: It not about the MAC-then-encrypt, it is about re-using the IV under the same key. The SIV mode modifies the IV with the message so that you may get rid of the case.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying